# What is the role of discrete resistors and capacitors in a motherboard?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, microprocessor, motherboard, mixed-signal

I know the basic function of resistors and capacitors. I know filters, oscillators, one-shot,  differentiator/integrator, ADC/DAC, power supplies, etc. But in a motherboard why are there so many external resistors and capacitors? How many of these analog circuits are there? Or does it have something to do with the copper transmission lines?

Comment: Pull ups and pull downs. Try googling them.

Comment: ... and filter capacitors, bypass capacitors, switching voltage regulator feedback resistors etc etc etc.

Comment: How are you telling the difference between SMD resistors and caps anyways? Are you just including resistors because you cannot tell the difference? Because most are probably decoupling caps, by far. I would expect most resistors to be termination resistors...though I would expect these to be arrays or integrated which you probably would not recognize as discretes.

Comment: and there's also a bunch of power supplies across a mainboard, mostly close to the devices that need a lot of dynamic power.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Arrays are rarely used on high density / high frequency applications like motherboard for computers and servers. Main reason is that arrays twist the layout where individual components can go closer to where needed and not add extra length to critical traces. Another is component value optimization for signal integrity tuning if needed. An array pretty much means a group of values are the same where optimization may require one to be different. Lastly I have studied this for high volume manufacturing and the costs of arrays are little different from the cost of (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  the equivalent discrete components. The big factories place more emphasis on reducing BOM line count than total BOM item count.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Makes sense. A pick and place machine and reflow oven does not lose the will to live soldering a thousand termination resistors.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, but assembly shops do charge by the location. If resistors cost $0.002 each, and arrays cost $0.01 each, but we pay $0.02 per location for pick and place machine time, arrays start to make sense again. (These numbers aren't unreasonable for volumes in the 10,000s per year, IME) Whether you can save space using arrays, and whether the signal integrity is affected are highly dependent on design details. And adding lines to the BOM only becomes very expensive in a big jump when you exceed the number of reels the handler can can hold.

Comment: Another thing many folks do not realize is just how many zero ohm resistors that are used on complex boards like server mother boards. These are used mainly so a board layout can be populated in many different build configurations. The cost and time of fully validating and qualifying a board design is high enough that there is great desire to be able cover a range of product levels with one layout.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Sure smaller shops do charge that way. During my tour of duty in the server board design business that was not the case. Board price quoting is so competitive in that industry that board factories were often selected based upon quoted pricing even before the Fab 1 schematics were completed. The sheer number of line items on a BOM was so great that it was probably more about how many machines needed to be cascaded on a line to just populate one side of the board,

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I'm working with some of the biggest CM's in the world, and they are giving a price per location, not just a blanket price per board. And even if they did quote a blanket price on the first job, the actual number of locations will affect how much the price can be negotiated down over time, or what they quote on the next design, etc.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Maybe some things have changed over time. I moved from doing the server board designs to doing internal chip set FW about seven or eight years ago. I do fully agree with your statement "what they quote on the next design". I suspect that this is the reason that it seemed from generation to generation different factories would be selected as they vied for the company's business.

Comment: Can't answer this without more information: what motherboard?  Capacitors could be local decoupling especially if we are talking high speed circuits, say on a computer. Resistors could be to limit transmission line effects or a simple 'pull-up' or 'pull-down'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of caps should be decoupling caps. Termination resistors should account for many (most? but am hesitant to say so) of the resistors.

Comment: Is there any rule on how you should place these discrete smd components? Such as to not bring about interference or any other unwanted effects that will cause the circuit to behave in an unpredictable manner.

Comment: @Joey There is  but its broader than what I think you have in mind. For general circuit design you should get Henry Ott's book Electromagnetic Compatibility. It's really good. His website under the "Tech Tips" is also really good but not as complete as the book. As you get into RF, analog, and transmission line stuff (like really high speed digital switching that requires terminations) you have to start just following the physics.

Answer (score 2):

They provide filtering, DC smoothing, adjustment (voltage, current, frequency of an IC), pull-ups and pull-downs, impedance matching, terminations, current limiting, DC blocking, basically all the functions that are included as options for ICs, that can't be placed inside ICs or that can be done cheaper or occupy less space than an additional IC.